# Best way to inherit class with data?

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance, user-controls

Not sure how noob or advanced this question is, but I've been having kind of trouble finding a good answer so thought I give it a try here.

To describe my question in words is the following. I have a program that Init's a "engine" at startup that is the source for all data and information for this program. The thing is right now if I write a new class right now I have to include it when the class is created.

```
public class ClassName(TMEngine engine)
{
......
}
```

What I wonder is if how I could use a "child : parent" class relation to have this on the parent so the only this I have to know is what its called.
I have written classes both for the `Form` and `UserControl` to have some extras in them so there is a parent class.

```
public partial class msgCtrlContainerCtrl : TMUserControl
{
     public msgCtrlContainerCtrl(TMEngine engine)
     {
        ......
     }
}
```

As this is a WinForms application I init the engine in the form, but would like all controls created in it used the same engine.

Setting up the engine on "Load-event" in the `TMUserControl` does not work right now as the `UserControl` will be initialized on "add" as a `UserControl`, and the `Load` event will be run much further behind this.

And you can not look for a parent to the control as the parent-relation has not been initialized yet when you do the "add" for a new control.

So any ideas how to solve this in the best way to place this engine in sync in my extended `UserControl` class I call `TMUserControl` here or dose it have to be in every class that uses it?

Comment: You're looking for a Singleton from the sounds of it

Comment: http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternSingleton.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
public class TMEngine
{
   private TMEngine() {}

   private static TMEngine instance;    
   public static TMEngine Instance
   {
      get 
      {
         if (instance == null)             
            instance = new TMEngine();             
         return instance;
      }
   }

   public string GetSomeStringData()
   {
       ...
   }
}
```

This will be your engine...  so you can go ahead and construct the way you want.
Now you need an abstract for all your classes that will use the engine.

```
public abstract class EnginedClass
{
    public static TMEngine Engine { get { return TMEngine.Instance; } };
}
```

Then just implement your classes using it:

```
public MyNewClass : EnginedClass
{
    ...
    public string GetSomeData()
    {
        ...
        return Engine.GetSomeStringData();
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: This might just be it! having a instance. will give it a shot. Thanks!

Comment: Notice how you will never explicitly instantiate TMEngine...  it is a singleton, so you just start using TMEngine.Instance and it will instantiate it for you.